# ¿Cómo recorrer cada registro de una tabla, hacer un procedimiento y actualizar un campo?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Quiero hacer un recorrido de cara uno de los registros de una tabla X en MySQL, en cada registro tomaré un valor de un registro anterior a ese y haré una multiplicación y actualizaré un campo del registro nuevo a ingresar.

Adjunto imagen, necesito tomar el Mileage del registro y restarlo con el mileage anterior, dividirlo entre Liters y actualizar el campo Efficiency en el registro.

[image]

Comment: Hola, either translate your question into English, or explore the Spanish language version of the site

Comment: Links, images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of or links to code, data or error messages.** Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/data/message into the post directly.

Comment: Para aclarar Necesitas tomar el ultimo registro del millage (id => 2) 200 y restarle (id =>1) 100.9 = 99.1
entonces dividir entre los litros del (id => 2) y actualizar (id =>2)? (200-100.1)/11=9.00909090909 al final efficiency del id=>2 debe ser igual a 9.00909090909 ?? tu aplicacion es en PHP ?

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy poco clara y no se entiende nada de lo que necesitas. podes arreglarla? si no va a terminar cerrada

Comment: Si asi mismo es, sip es en php, lo que me recomendaron era que lo hiciera en mysql ese proceso por si llegase a fallar php

Comment: el campo de efficiency en id=>2 esta como 0 porque depende directamente del registro anterior para actualizar ese campo

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso este seria el query en el primer caso

```
a) mileage = 100.9
b) litters = 10
c) efficiency = 0
```

En el registro 2

```
a) mileage = 200
b) litters = 11
c) efficiency = (200-(SELECT mileage from demo2 order by id desc limit 1))/11  ==> equivalente a 9.00909090909091
```

En el registro3

```
a) mileage = 500
b) litters = 15
c) efficiency = (500-(SELECT mileage from demo2 order by id desc limit 1))/15 ==> equivalente a 20
```

Los querys son los siguientes:

1)

```
INSERT INTO demo2 (mileage, litters,efficiency) VALUES (100.9,10,0);
```

2)

```
INSERT INTO demo2 (mileage, litters,efficiency) VALUES (200,11,
                                                        (200-(SELECT mileage from demo2 order by id desc limit 1))/11
                                                       );
```

3)

```
INSERT INTO demo2 (mileage, litters,efficiency) VALUES (500,15,
                                                        (500-(SELECT mileage from demo2 order by id desc limit 1))/15
                                                       );
```